# TreePosition with multiple (not just node data) conditions

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering, trees, expression-manipulation

Given a `Tree` object, `TreePosition` takes patterns only on the "data" of the node plus a level spec.

```
t = Tree[a, {Tree[b, None], Tree[c, {Tree[d, None]}], Tree[e, {Tree[f, None], 
       Tree[g, None], Tree[h, {Tree[e, None]}]}]}]
TreePosition[t, e] (* {{3, 3}, {3}} *)
```

But what about using other information on the node, like depth, parent, children, etc.?

Essentially, **how can one do this sort of operation** (with obviously invented notation):

```
TreePosition[t, And[
  MemberQ[{e, z}, #Value],                      (* data is e or z*)
  #Depth >= 1,                                  (* occurs in 2-4th row *)
  Length[#Children]>=1,                         (* more than 1 kid *) 
  ToCharacterCode[ToString[#Parent]][[1]] == 97 (* parent is a *)
  ...                                           (* yada yada *)
 ]
]
```

Or is there no way until something like `Supplied` exists?

Comment: There's currently no built-in way to do this sort of operation.